# Laravel 5.6 - the validate() function doesn't return 422 with invalid input

Tags: php, laravel

According to Laravel 5.6's [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields),

> When using the validate method during an AJAX request, Laravel will not generate a redirect response. Instead, Laravel generates a JSON response ... This JSON response will be sent with a 422 HTTP status code.

I can't really see if it returns 422.

Here is a snippet of my experimentation.

```
public function registerWithEmail(Request $request)
{
    request()->validate([
        'name'     => ['required'],
        'email'    => ['required', 'email', 'unique:customers'],
        'password' => ['required', 'min:6'],
    ]);

    return Customer::create([
        'name'     => $request->input('name'),
        'email'    => $request->input(email),
        'password' => Hash::make($request->input(password)),
    ]);
}
```

When the input data is valid, HTTP status code is 201.

However, when it's invalid, the code is 302.

For example...

```
/** @test */
public function canNotRegisterCustomerWithSameEmail()
{
    $response = $this->post('/api/register', [
        'name'     => 'Valid Input',
        'email'    => 'blah@example.com',
        'password' => 'secret',
    ]);

    $response2 = $this->post('/api/register', [
        'name'     => 'Duplicate Email i.e. invalid',
        'email'    => 'blah@example.com',
        'password' => 'secret',
    ]);

    $response->assertStatus(201);
    //This is fine.
    $response2->assertStatus(422);
    //This fails, resulting in
    //"Expected status code 422 but received 302."

    $this->assertEquals(1, Customer::count());
    //This is fine
}
```

Do you see anything I'm doing wrong?
Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: It's obvious. When it's invalid it redirects you to a form to make some fixes. Hence you get `302`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the `post` method, which does *not* mimic an AJAX request. For regular HTTP requests that fail validation, Laravel returns with a `302`, so that the browser redirects you back to the previous page.

To test your controller's response for AJAX requests, use the `json` method:

```php
$this->json('post', '/api/register', [
    'name'     => 'Duplicate Email i.e. invalid',
    'email'    => 'blah@example.com',
    'password' => 'secret',
]);
```